# Failed to load Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 axios react post request

Tags: reactjs, post, http-status-code-404, axios

I have this express end point :

```
http://localhost:3008/projects
```

this end point is has a post request function look like this :

```
exports.create_a_project = function(req, res) {
  var new_project = new Project(req.body);
  new_project.save(function(err, project) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(project);
  });
};
```

when i use for example postman to text it. it works perfectly:

i used this object :

```
{"name": "ee", "description": "eewe", "url": "ewe", "about": "ewewe","picture":"ssd"}
```

my PROBLEM **
i send this object from my react app using axios as a post request like this :

```
const addProject = function(newProject) {

  let url = 'http://localhost:3008/projects';
  let data = {
    'name': 'ee',
    'description': 'eewe',
    'url': 'ewe',
    'about': 'ewewe',
    'picture': 'ssd',
  };
  return axios.post(url, data).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

it never work never 
I get this response :

```
Failed to load http://localhost:3008/projects: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404.

OPTIONS http://localhost:3008/projects 404 (Not Found)
```

my back application which hold my apis its cores look like that :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000'];
  var origin = req.headers.origin;
  if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  }
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  return next();
});
```